# Laravel Route conditions

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have countries model, also tag and category. And URLs for them not contains prefix or ids

*Mysite.org/spain* <— this is country

*Mysite/politics* <- this is category

*Mysite/population* <— this is tag

How to check one one by one these URLs?

I try use middleware

```
Route::get(‘/{slug}’, ‘CountryController@show’)->middleware(‘CheckCountryPath’)
Route::get(‘/{slug}’, ‘CategoryController@show’)->middleware(‘CheckCategoryPath’)
Route::get(‘/{slug}’, ‘TagController@show’)->middleware(‘CheckTagPath’)
```

in middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // Contru checking logick
        // if country model has this slug

        return $next($request);

        // else continue

    }
```

How to say in middleware if model has not this slug continue checking other routs, do not redirect

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your route at the end of your `web.php` file.

You need to process your slug in a single Middlware that will redirect to the proper Controller:

```
class ChangeControllerMiddleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        $route = $request->route();

        if($country) // Country Check Logic
            $controller = '\App\Http\Controllers\CountryController@show';

        // If not Country Category Logic ...
        elseif($category)
            $controller = '\App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController@show';

        // else 404
        else
           abort(404);

        $routeAction = array_merge($route->getAction(), [
            'uses'       => $controller,
            'controller' => $controller,
        ]);

        $route->setAction($routeAction);
        $route->controller = false;

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to check 3 models, and even if I check slug in in Controller and slug don't math I havto return not found. But I want to check  Route::get('/{slug}', ‘CountryController@show’) then Route::get('/{slug}', ‘CategoryController@show’), Route::get('/{slug}', ‘TagController@show’) and after that return 404

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer so it can help others as well 

Comment: I have lover laravel version, $route->getAction() not recognized